# Laravel 6 Can perform user restricted actions even after logout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have my website opened in two separate tabs in a browser.

I am using `laravel/ui` for authentication, i have a delete anchor tag which deletes blogs.

When i click logout button in one tab it logs out. If i refresh the other tab it takes me to login page as expected but if don't refresh and i click delete, it takes me to login page after deleting blog.

Why am i able to perform delete action after logout, even though i have auth middleware in my controller.

Also if i do the same with add blog action it gives me `419 | Page Expired` error which is how it should be for delete as well i guess

And how to prevent it.

**Delete Blog link**

```
<a href="/blogs/delete/{{ $blog->id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

**Add Blog Form**

```
<form action="/blogs" method="POST">
    @csrf
    ...
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/blogs/delete/{blog_id}', 'BlogController@delete')
    ->name('blogs.delete');
Route::post('/blogs', 'BlogController@store')
->name('blogs.store');
```

**Controller**

```
class BlogController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    private function checkBlogExist($blog_id)
    {
        // Check if blog exists
        $blog = Blog::find($blog_id);
        if (isset($blog)) {
            return $blog;
        }
        else {
            abort(404);
        }
    }

    private function checkBlogBelongs($blog_id) {
        // Check if blog exists
        $blog = $this->checkBlogExist($blog_id);
        // Check if blog belongs to auth user
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

        if ($blog->user->id == $user_id) {
            return [$blog, $user_id];
        }
        else {
            abort(403, 'Unauthorized action');
        }
    }

    // Add Blog
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Accept user request and add blog
        $fields = $request->input('blog');
        $blog = new Blog;

        foreach ($fields as $field => $value) {
            $blog->$field = $value;
        }

        // Add blog info to db
        // Check if user exists
        $user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);
        if (isset($user)) {
            $user->blogs()->save($blog);
        }
        else {
            abort(403, 'Unauthorized action');
        }
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    // Delete blog
    public function delete($blog_id)
    {
        // Check if blog exists
        // Check if blog belongs to user
        [$blog] = $this->checkBlogBelongs($blog_id);
        // Delete blog and all it's comments, likes
        $blog->delete();
        return back();
    }
}
```

**Update**

It doesn't actually deletes it but asks for login credentials.

I was logging in with same credentials **after** which it deletes it, my bad, but why does add blog gives `419 | Page Expired` whereas delete takes me to login page.

**Additional Problem**

And if someone else clicked on the delete button while user have logged out, login page will be displayed and if the same user login again there blog will be deleted, even though they never clicked the delete button.

Delete action shouldn't be performed after user login again, user must click the delete button again to do so or have some popup for confirmation.

Comment: Your auth middleware is mostly not present on the deleting route. Can you share the routes and the controller related to this issue ?

Comment: Added related code @N69S

Comment: Are you using a custom logout method or you're using the default ones ?

Comment: I'm using the default one, where is it defined though

Comment: in `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers@logout` by default and it has `$request->session()->invalidate();` in it which prevents your issue.

Comment: Add blog works fine,  check updated code @N69S

Comment: You are not using Laravel to its full potential. Use [dependency injection](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers) to pass a `Blog` object directly to your `delete()` method. If it doesn't exist the routing engine will return 404 automatically. Use a [policy](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization#creating-policies) if you want to ensure authorization.

Comment: Even if it were necessary, your `checkBlogExist()` method does not work. The variable will always be set, but it might be `null`.

Comment: use the POST method in delete function and send $blog_id in the POST, so that after login again it won't delete because there won't be $blog_id and you can check it and redirect accordingly.

Comment: @KulshreshthK Thanks, works gr8, gives me 404 after i login again